# Почему не происходит импорт базы данных MySQL через консоль?

Tags: mysql, консоль

Почему верхняя команда не импортирует базу данных, а выдает какую-то помощь?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как минимум между `-p` и паролем не должно быть пробела

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте команду:

```
mysql -uroot -p4722388 employees < c:\\BD\FULL\employees.sql
```

т.е. то же самое, что у Вас было, но без пробелов после `-u` и `-p`.
И на забудьте затем сменить пароль для пользователя **root**, т.к. благодаря Вашем скриншоту его теперь знает весь мир ;)